# upgrade a kernel when in chroot. how to?

Tags: kernel, iso, chroot, uck

I am trying to build a custom cd using uck. Now, i want to upgrade the kernel, remove the old kernel and then create the iso. I am able to upgrade the kernel but I am not able to switch to the new kernel as I cannot reboot ( as its a chroot session).

Is it possible to switch to the new kernel and remove the old kernel?

Comment: The running kernel and the kernel image within the chroot should be unconnected removing the current kernel from the chroot image should be safe.

Comment: i think that didnt work. If i remove the present kernel, i am getting errors while creating a boot image for the latest kernel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ISO image, updating the Kernel will create problems with all packages related to that version of the kernel. It is like a waterfall effect. You change the kernel and any packages in your ISO that have relation with the old kernel might show problems when installing them.

In any case I also tried to upgrade the kernel, my case was 2.6.36 to 2.6.39. No luck there was no option for me at that time but for what I have checked here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/uck/+bug/664709 and here: https://answers.launchpad.net/uck/+question/96338 there has been work to accomplish this using some methods.

In all cases, the problems described in those links suggest that doing the upgrade like I mentioned will create other problems: Not booting, problems looking for packages, package managers having upgrade problems with the kernel, etc..